# Making async calls with nodejs and express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have 2 functions, the first:

```
router.post('/getStances', function(req, res, next) {
    var text = '{"success":"0"}';
    text = queries.getStances(req.body.issues[0], req.body.issues[1], req.body.issues[2], req.body.issues[3]);
    var obj = JSON.parse(result);
    res.send(obj);
});
```

the second:

```
getStances: function (a, b, c, d) {
        var sendback = '{"stances":[';
        sendback += '{"1":[';
        var querytext = "SELECT * FROM allIssues WHERE topicname = '"+ a +"'";
        query = client.query(querytext,function (callback) {
            query.on('row', (row) => {
                sendback += "{" + '"'+row['topicstance']+'"' + " : "  +  '"'+ row['topicdescription'] + '"'+ "} , ";
                console.log(sendback);
            });
        });

        querytext = "SELECT * FROM allIssues WHERE topicname = '"+ b +"'";
        query = client.query(querytext);
            query.on('row', (row) => {
                sendback += "{" + '"'+ row['topicstance'] + '"'+ " : " + '"'+ row['topicdescription'] + '"'+ "} , ";
            });
            query.on('end', () => {
                sendback += "]}";
                sendback += "]}";
                client.end();
                return sendback;
            });
        }
```

The first function is called by the client app, it then calls `getStances` which makes DB calls and should return a JSON string that has all the db info inside, but instead when `text = getStances()` is called, `text` is set to `undefined` and the rest of router function runs, then it tries to parse `text` to JSON but since its `undefined`, it doesn't work. How do I make the router function asynchronous so that it will wait for `text = getStances()` to complete before it continues with the rest of the code? I have tried callbacks and promises but I get more or less the same results, I am unsure of exactly how they work so maybe I used them incorrectly. Can someone give any examples of how I could fix this?

Comment: Double-check the documentation for `client.query()`, shouldn't the first argument of the callback be an Error object? And do not build your JSON string using strings -- it's ugly; simply use an object. When you send an object as a response, it will converted into a JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getStances()` needs a way to indicate that it is finished – a callback or promise.

Your function signature could look like:

```
getStances: function (a, b, c, d, callback) {
     someAsynFunction(arg, function(err, result){
         if (err) return callback(err)   // errors go first by convention
         callback(null, results) // callback(error, result)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it by passing a function into `getStances()` for the callback:

```
let i = req.body.issues // for brevity
text = queries.getStances(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], function(err, result){
    if (err) return console.log("error: ", err)
    var obj = JSON.parse(result);
    res.send(obj);
);
```

This is a basic node pattern.

It's not clear what DB client you are using, but I suspect you have another problem in your code.

It looks like you are making two async calls in `getStances()` and you are counting on the first one finishing before the second. This is likely to break, so you'll need to find out how your client communicates that it is finished (is there a `query.on('finished')` or similar?) if you want to insure they happen sequentially.